# Django: ajax POST sending data of array of objects not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I’m creating a JSON object and pushing it into an array.

```
var json_array = []
    var edit_info = {
                        'name': str_name,
                        'id': str_id,
                    };
    json_array.push(JSON.stringify(edit_info))
```

and trying to send the `json_array` in a POST request.

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: req_url,
        type: req_method,
        data: {'req_data': json_array},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data.message)
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Some error has occured.")
        }
    });
```

I am seeing strange behaviour from the browser (Chrome): it seems it passes two arrays as the post data:

```
req_data[]:{"name":"naveen","id":"11"}
req_data[]:{"name":"kavi","id":"13"}
```

Shouldn't it be like  this?

```
req_data[]: [{"name":"naveen","id":"11"}', {"name":"kavi","id":"13"}]
```

But in views.py `request.POST` shows post data as it should be:

```
{u'req_data[]': [u'{"name":"naveen","id":"11"}', u'{"name":"kavi","id":"13"}']}
```

But `request.POST['req_data[]']`shows

```
{"name":"kavi","id":"13"}
```

I have no clue what is happening here. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use QueryDict.getlist method for request.POST and then deserialize each list item from str to dict:

```
import json
data = request.POST.getlist('req_data[]', [])
data = [json.loads(item) for item in data]
```